# How can I get the x and y dimensions of a ndarray - Numpy / Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shapes

I'm wondering if I can get the x and y dimensions of a ndarray separately. I know that I can use  `ndarray.shape` to get a tuple representing the dimensions, but how can I separate this in x and y information?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use tuple unpacking.

```
y, x = a.shape
```

Comment: Thank you. Googling it and founding nothing! :D

Comment: `.shape` is a property of a numpy array, not a method.

Comment: Note: `.shape()` (with parenthesis) was initially mentioned in the question itself, so it looks more like inattention rather than logical mistake in the answer.

Comment: It was my mistake.  It is a property, not a method.  Also, I got the coordinates backwards.

Answer (score 14):

```
height, width = a.shape
```

Note, however, that `ndarray` has matrix coordinates (`i,j`), which are opposite to image coordinates (`x,y`). That is:

```
i, j = y, x  # and not x, y
```

Also, Python tuples support indexing, so you can access separate dimensions like this:

```
dims = a.shape
height = dims[0]
width = dims[1]
```

Answer (score 4):

`ndarray.shape()` will throw a `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable.` because it's not a function, it's a value.

What you want to do is just tuple unpack `.shape` without the `()`.  Example:

```
>> import numpy
>> ndarray = numpy.ndarray((20, 21))
>> ndarray.shape
(20, 21)
>> x, y = ndarray.shape
>> x
20
>> y
21
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html

Comment: In your second paragraph, you probably meant `.shape`, not `.size`. `.size` contains total number of elements.