# How to get grabCut to work opencv python with GC_INIT_WITH_MASK

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to get the messi example to work:  https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html

In my setup, I want the entire process to be automated.

For example, I grab an image from the web:
http://wanderlustandlipstick.com/travel-tips/opting-out-full-body-scanners/

[image: Image Scan - imagescan.png]

And using some opencv tools I autogenerate the following mask:

[image: Image Mask - imagemask.png]

Black is supposed to be a certain background, White is supposed to be a certain foreground, and Grey is supposed to be unknown.

Following the messi tutorial (https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html), below is my code.  However, it only shows the small white circle area, as if it is treating grey like black (certain background)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("imagescan.png")
dimy = np.shape(img)[0] # seems to be backwards (x,y)
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490721/how-can-i-get-the-x-and-y-dimensions-of-a-ndarray-numpy-python
dimx = np.shape(img)[1]
mask = np.zeros((dimy,dimx),np.uint8) # zeroes as array/matrix size of image
bgdModel = fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)    

newmask = cv2.imread('imagemask.png',0)

# informational purposes
removeBg = (newmask == 0)
removeBg = np.ravel(removeBg)
np.bincount(removeBg)
keepFg = (newmask == 255)
keepFg = np.ravel(keepFg)
np.bincount(keepFg)

#otherEl = (not (newmask == 0 or newmask == 255)) # throws error
#otherEl = np.ravel(otherEl)
#np.bincount(otherEl)

# appears at least one of each elements is required
# otherwise throws bgdSamples.empty error / fgdSamples.empty error
mask[newmask == 0] = 0
mask[newmask == 255] = 1

mask, bgdModel, fgdModel = cv2.grabCut(img,mask,None,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)

mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img2 = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]
plt.imshow(img2),plt.colorbar(),plt.show()
```

The result is just a mask off the circle, as if the gray area is being treated as black.

[image: Output is not what I want!]

Comment: Which opencv tools can be used to autogenerate the mask?? I am doing a small project of extracting hair from portrait image. Need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mask image, you basically have 3 colors: black,white,grey. In the following lines of code, you're setting background and foreground, but not the probable foreground.

```
mask[newmask == 0] = 0
mask[newmask == 255] = 1
```

Try using using OpenCV provided constants (`cv2.GC_BGD` etc) to avoid confusion.

```
# this line sets the grey areas - meaning any color not 0 and not 255 - to probable foreground.
mask = np.where(((newmask>0) & (newmask<255)),cv2.GC_PR_FGD,0).astype('uint8')
mask[newmask == 0] = cv2.GC_BGD
mask[newmask == 255] = cv2.GC_FGD
```

[image: Result].